How to make Gsoap XML parsing read correct elements from response messages and ignore wrong/corrupted ones?
According to onvif documentaion
https://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema/onvif.xsd
ImagingSettings20 type has a tt:FocusConfiguration20 element
    <xs:complexType name="ImagingSettings20">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Type describing the ImagingSettings of a VideoSource. The supported options and ranges can be obtained via the GetOptions command.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            ...
            <xs:element name="Focus" type="tt:FocusConfiguration20" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Focus configuration.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>

            ...
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
    </xs:complexType>

Imaging wsdl
https://www.onvif.org/ver20/imaging/wsdl/imaging.wsdl
However one of the ONVIF cameras sends the following GetImagingSettingsResponse:
        <timg:GetImagingSettingsResponse>
            <timg:ImagingSettings>
                <tt:Brightness>0</tt:Brightness>
                <tt:ColorSaturation>0</tt:ColorSaturation>
                <tt:Contrast>0</tt:Contrast>
                <tt:Sharpness>50</tt:Sharpness>
                <tt:Focus>
                    <tt:AutoFocusModes>AUTO</tt:AutoFocusModes>
                    <tt:AutoFocusModes>MANUAL</tt:AutoFocusModes>
                    <tt:DefaultSpeed>
                        <tt:Min>1</tt:Min>
                        <tt:Max>1</tt:Max>
                    </tt:DefaultSpeed>
                    <tt:NearLimit>
                        <tt:Min>10</tt:Min>
                        <tt:Max>2000</tt:Max>
                    </tt:NearLimit>
                    <tt:FarLimit>
                        <tt:Min>0</tt:Min>
                        <tt:Max>0</tt:Max>
                    </tt:FarLimit>
                </tt:Focus>
            </timg:ImagingSettings>
        </timg:GetImagingSettingsResponse>

So instead of tt:FocusConfiguration20 it sends tt:FocusOptions20 in response
Which is completely wrong
GSOAP generated C++ code fails to parse such response and stops parsing right after it finds the wrong element tt:Focus
However I would like to have a possibility to parse at least the correct fields from the response message:
                <tt:Brightness>0</tt:Brightness>
                <tt:ColorSaturation>0</tt:ColorSaturation>
                <tt:Contrast>0</tt:Contrast>
                <tt:Sharpness>50</tt:Sharpness>

And just ignore the failed element tt:Focus (only in case it has tt:FocusOptions20 type insead of tt:FocusConfiguration20 or wrong/corrupted)
If tt:Focus is correct, I want to parse it
Could someone suggest the best way to do that?
Thanks in advance
Any help would be greatly appreciated

You have an xml that does not meet the schema.  It should be fixed.  Anybody who generates an XML file with a schema should always performed a schema check before distributing corrupt xml files.

Yes, You are absolutely right about that. XML should be fixed
However it is a third-party device
I can't fix it
The only thing I can do - is some reasonable workaround to handle this case

I can fix it with c#, but do not know gsoap.
